# Принадлежит ли точка фигуре

Tags: python, алгоритм

Имеется фигура которая определяется тремя вершинами и у которой каждая сторона - это либо часть дуги полуокружности, центр которой находиться на прямой y=0, либо часть вертикального луча.

Из данных получаемых программой есть координаты x,y каждой из 3-х точе, а также координата точки для которой нужно определить принадлежность/нет к этой фигуре.

А также нужно узнать максимальный радиус из окружностей формирующих фигуру.

Какие формулы и алгоритмы нужно использовать для решения данной задачи?

Comment: Покажите пример такой чудо-фигуры.

Comment: треугольник с дугами вместо сторон

Comment: и если что, часть вертикального луча это ось ординат

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это задача по геометрии, а не по программированию

Comment: У вас написано "часть вертикального угла", а не "часть вертикального луча". Что такое "часть вертикального угла"?

Answer (score 2):

Найти центры и радиусы дуг окружностей по двум известным точкам и известной ординате центра нетрудно - достаточно составить уравнения окружности для обеих точек и вычесть их друг из друга, чтобы избавиться от радиуса и получить абсциссу центра, а затем уже вычислить 
радиус.

По принадлежности контуру - нужно определить, входит ли точка в каждую из окружностей, и скомбинировать эти признаки в зависимости от того, является ли соответствующая дуга выпуклой или вогнутой относительно внутренней области.
Или подход, известный для многоугольников - посчитать количество пересечений горизонтального луча с данными дугами. Нечетное количество - внутри.

Про нечто вертикальное пока невнятно, и рисунков-примеров нет, так что дальше гадать не буду.